# "Referral Denied" Implementation

Tags: security, web-applications

I was looking for a way to protect a web service from "Synthetic queries". Read this [security stack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/protection-against-synthetic-queries) question for more details.

It seemed that I had little alternative, until I came across [NSE India's](http://www.nseindia.com) website which implements a certain kind of measure against such synthetic queries.

I would like to know how could they have implemented a protection which works somewhat this way: You go to their website and search for a quote, lets say, RELIANCE, we get a page displaying the latest quote.

On analysis we find that the query being sent across is something like:

```
 http://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/equities/ajaxGetQuote.jsp?symbol=RELIANCE&series=EQ
```

But when we directly copy paste the query in the browser, it returns "referral denied".

I guess such a procedure may also help me. Any ideas how I may implement something similar?

Comment: Whenever you ask a security question, you first need to identify 1) What are you trying to protect? 2) who is the attacker?

Comment: @CodeIn: If you read the security stack question (linked in the OP) you will get proper idea.

Comment: I didn't notice that other question was by you. In that case server side validation is the one and only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't help you. Faking a referrer is trivial. The only protection against queries the attacker constructs is server side validation.

Referrers sometimes can be used to sometimes prevent hotlinking from other websites, but even that is rather hard to do since certain programs create fake referrers and you don't want to block those users.

The problems referrer validation could help against other websites trying to manipulate the users browser into accessing your site. Like some kinds of cross site request forgery. But it does never protect against malicious users. Against those the only thing that helps is server side validation. You can never trust the client if you don't trust the user of that client.

Comment: +1 Ah! May be you right. I was reading over Google and came across something similar.